# Argument 'ArrayRow':BC30333: Value of type 'Integer()' cannot be converted to 'Object()' because 'Integer' is not a reference type

Tags: uipath, uipath-studio

I am Facing this error in UiPath Automation.

Argument 'ArrayRow':BC30333: Value of type 'Integer()' cannot be converted to 'Object()' because 'Integer' is not a reference type

I am trying to add ArrayRow Argument (Example:- {x,y}). then this error is occure below i Attach Image what i use and which error is faceing

X and Y is type Integer

[Here the Error Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4lIxh.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to convert your variable to Object like below.

[image]

Refer this link for detail info: https://docs.uipath.com/activities/other/latest/workflow/add-data-row

Snippet from link:
[image]